# Accessing instance variable in `each` loop

Tags: ruby, loops, each

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
customer1.shopping_cart.each do |item|
  puts("#{item.name}")
```

The `Item` class has an `attr_reader` for the instance variable name.

Comment: Instead of typing the code in here, why don't you type the code in your Ruby interpreter instead, then you would see that it works already, and that the answer is "yes, something like this is possible, in fact, *exactly* this is possible".

Answer (score 1):

```
customer1.shopping_cart.each do |item|
  puts("#{item.name}")
end
```

This will put names for every item from the `customer1.shopping_cart` collection (presumably array or set)

UPD: A bit more idiomatic syntax:

```
customer1.shopping_cart.map(&:name).each(&method(:puts))
```

Comment: `puts item.name` is sufficient.

Comment: Another fan of point-free style, nice! :-D Note: `puts` will print array elements one per line, so just `puts customer1.shopping_cart.map(&:name)` is enough.